# Capturing events in javascript

Tags: javascript, events, addeventlistener, event-bubbling, event-capturing

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<body>
<div id = 'div' style = 'width:100px;height:100px;background:#000000;'></div>
<script type = 'text/javascript'>
document.getElementById('div').addEventListener('click',happen(),true);
function happen()
{
    alert(1)
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In the above code why the event is triggered when the page loads and not triggered when  i click on the div...Also which is the correct event name click or onclick....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you've immediately called the function, and passed its null result to `addEventListener()`.

It should be:

```
document.getElementById('div').addEventListener('click',happen,true);
```

If you want to pass arguments to `happen`, you'd have to write this:

```
document.getElementById('div').addEventListener('click', function() {
    happen(args_here, ...); 
}, true);
```

Answer (score 3):

You're calling the function *immediately* and passing its return value to `addEventListener`, just like any other function call.
Take out the `()`.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
document.getElementById('div').addEventListener('click',happen,true);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with this line:

```
document.getElementById('div').addEventListener('click',happen(),true);
```

You should should only be passing the name of the function `happen` but since you added the parentheses, you are passing the result.

Try this instead:

```
document.getElementById('div').addEventListener('click',happen,true);
```

Comment: so how do i pass arguments  for the function

Comment: @JinuJD you'd have to wrap the function call in _another_ anonymous function

Comment: sorry i dont get it...what is meant by wrapping..can you show me an example?

Answer (score 0):

As the other answerers have said, taking out the () will fix the problem.

An alternative, and a good practice for OO Javascript, is to wrap the function inside a `function(){   }`, like so:

`document.getElementById('div').addEventListener('click',function(){happen()},true);`

That will retain scope if the callback needs to execute within an object (in this case it does not).

Comment: IMHO, it's _not_ good practise to introduce a new scope unless you actually need it.

Comment: Yeah, I usually do need it ;) And the fewer global window objects the better.

Comment: your version introduces no more nor less "global window objects" (I presume you actually mean "global variables") than just writing `happen`.

Answer (score 0):

The event handler does not need parenthesis

```
 document.getElementById('div1').addEventListener('click',happen,true);
```